# Oxymoron in poetry and prose

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Can we use **oxymorons** to **magnify dramatic effects** on **poetry** and **proses**, can't we? (rhythm, tone, expressiveness, etc). When can we use it **appropriately**? I was wondering if you could help me give some **specific contexts.**

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You can do anything you want in poetry and prose except ask permission.

Comment: Are you sure you know what **oxymoron** is? It is nothing to do with rhythm or tone.